# Dockers NET I/O stats for host network mode

Tags: linux, docker, networking, containers

I want to benefit from the enhanced performance that `--network host` can provide, but at the same time is crucial for me to know how much traffic was generated by the container. I used to use `docker stats` for this, but it's always `0/0` for the `NET I/O` field when in the `host` networking mode. Any ways to achieve it?

Comment: `--network host` generally disables Docker networking, so I'd be surprised if any Docker-level metrics were available.  The main container process will have the same network environment and tracking as any other process on the host.

Comment: It makes sense, for sure. Is there any way to track how much traffic was sent by a container process? Even if it's going through eth0.